# How to know if an interpolation task is ill-conditioned?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, numerical-optimization

Given a number of datapoints (e.g., 4), how can one determine if the interpolation task is well or ill-conditioned? Can anyone give me a concrete example of an ill- vs well-conditioned interpolation task?

Comment: Have you tried writing your interpolation problem as a linear system of equations and then looking at the condition number of this linear system of equations?

Comment: good point! That's the solution! Thx!

Comment: You might consider what happens if you have some of the data points at the same $x$ value with different $y$ values.  You might also consider what happens as the number of data points (and the degree of a polynomial interpolant) increases.

Comment: And in this context, in an exam, the polynomial function 9th-sqrt(e^x)  (not 2nd-sqrt) that should be interpolated using 21 points, was given. They asked what would be better to use polynomial interpolation or newton divided differences for this specific function and why? What's the order of this polynomial? And what's the dimension (m*n) of the Matrix V. (Vandermode-Matrix)? I would say newton divided differences is better. The order is 20, because of 21 points. Not sure of my answer. But what would you say? Could you help me answering that questions please?